# Reverse for 'admin_update' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin_update/(?P<lesson_id>[^/]+)$']

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-urls

I'm trying to pass arguments to edit table values.
Would be grateful if anyone could breakdown the solution.

views.py
`

```
#@login_required(login_url='/admin_login/')
def AdminManageRequests(request):
    lessons = Lesson.objects.all()
    return render(request,'admin/manage_requests.html',{'lessons':lessons})


def AdminUpdateRequests(request, lesson_id):
    lesson = Lesson.objects.get(pk=lesson_id)
    form = StudentRequestForm(request.POST or None, instance=lesson)
    context = {
        'lesson':lesson, 'form':form
    }
    return render(request, 'admin/update_requests.html',context)
```

`

urls.py
`

```
path('admin_update/<lesson_id>', views.AdminUpdateRequests, name='admin_update'),
```

`

manage_requests.html
`

```
{% extends 'admin/admin_home_base.html' %}
{% block admin_content %}
<div>
  <h3 class="display-8" style="text-align:center">
      Admin Lesson Request Management
  </h3>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <p style="text-align:center">
      You can view fulfilled and unfulfilled lesson requests.
  </p>
  <p class="lead" style="text-align:center">
    {% include 'admin/partials/fulfilled_lessons.html' %}
    <br>
    {% include 'admin/partials/unfulfilled_lessons.html' %}
  </p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

`

lessons_table_base.html
`

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h5 class="card-title">{% block card_title %}{% endblock %}</h5>
      <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0">
        <table class="table table-hover text-nowrap">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Lesson ID</th>
              <th>Lesson Name</th>
              <th>Student</th>
              <th>Teacher</th>
              <th>Interval (Days)</th>
              <th>Duration (Minutes)</th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          {% for lesson in lessons %}                       
          {% block lessons_content %}
          {% endblock %}
          {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`

fulfilled_lessons.html
`

```
{% extends 'admin/partials/lessons_table_base.html' %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block card_title %}
Fulfilled Requests&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="bi-send-check-fill"></i>
{% endblock %}
{% block lessons_content %}
{% if not lesson.is_request %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ lesson.lesson_id }}</td>
    <td>{{ lesson.lesson_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ lesson.student }}</td>
    <td>{{ lesson.teacher }}</td>
    <td>{{ lesson.interval }}</td>
    <td>{{ lesson.duration }}</td>
    <td>
        <!-- admin edit lesson here -->
        <a href="{% url 'admin_update' lesson.id %}">update</a>  
        <!-- admin delete lesson here -->
        <a href="#" class="nav-link" role="button" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove lesson">
            <span class="bi-dash-square"></span>
        </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

`

updates_requests.html (will add more code when the issue's resolved.)
`

```
{% extends 'admin/admin_home_base.html' %}
{% block admin_content %}
<div>
    <h2  style="text-align:center">
    Update Lesson Request
    </h2>
    <hr class="my-4">
    <p style="text-align:center">
        You can update lessons to the system.
    </p>
    <form action="" method=POST>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-secondary">
    </form>
   
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

`

tracebacks
`

```
Internal Server Error: /admin_managerequests/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/lessons/views.py", line 55, in AdminManageRequests
    return render(request,'admin/manage_requests.html',{'lessons':lessons})
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 188, in render
    return template.render(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 173, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 309, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 443, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/jaeholee/SEG-Small-Group-Project/hyena/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 677, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'admin_update' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin_update/(?P<lesson_id>[^/]+)$']
```

`

I have tried some solutions but nothing worked. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `<int:lesson_id>` not only `<lesson_id>` as by default (when nothing is given) it is considered as string type so:

```py
path('admin_update/<int:lesson_id>/', views.AdminUpdateRequests, name='admin_update'),
```

I'd also recommend you to use [`get_object_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) so:

```
lesson = get_object_or_404(Lesson,pk=lesson_id)
```

> **Note:** Always add `/` at the end of every route.